# How to search for specific string in mysql table

Tags: mysql

**Context**

I'm creating a comment system where users can use the "@" symbol to mention other users' usernames. I want to be able to go into the database and search through the comments table so that comments that include "@_____" (insert username) are given. However, it should only contain that username in the word; if there's a username `randomusername` and I search for `randomusername` in the query, I don't want names like `randomusernameextended` to show up because part of its string is what I queried. Additionally, there should be able to be more than just the username in the result, which is why using `WHERE comment = "@____"` doesn't work; it only returns rows that ONLY include that username. I want to return rows that simply contain the username in the message (example: "@____ random comment here" is returned when I query the username).

**Question**

How do I search a mySQL table for a specific row, one that includes the specific string I searched for but can also contain more text?

**Things I Have Tried**

I have already tried using the `%LIKE%` operator to return results that include the username string. The problem is that I only want the username to be in the one word I return and nothing more, but given the nature of the operator, I can't search for the username `randomusername` without getting `randomusernameextended`, as I mentioned.

Let me know if there is any confusion. Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever use `LIKE 'a%' that finds any values that start with "a" this method is like a facebook when mentioning

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales what if "a" is located in the middle of string

Comment: Then it should be combined with two SQL queries that uses distinct to filter two values that found in two queries

Comment: Note that there is the `REGEXP` keyword also in MySQL if you're familiar with regexes (I don't know which is slower with `LIKE`), it can be useful, as you username may be separated with something else than a space (dot, comma...) so that `LIKE '%@randomuser %'` won't find them

Comment: in other words, the query should handle three cases. 1. `pattern<special_char>%` 2. `%<special_char>pattern` 3. `%<special_char>pattern<special_char>%`. where special char includes spaces/tabs as well

Comment: @Kaddath So you're saying that using `REGEXP` would allow me to consider the username along with any combination of punctuation?

Comment: @CarsonD yes, exactly, I added an answer that can fit your case

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a regex pattern here, something like

```
WHERE comment REGEXP ".*@randomusername([[:>:]].*|$)"
```

regex explanation:

- `.` means "any character" and `*` means "any number of times" (0 to unlimited times)
- `[[:>:]]` a word ending, anything that is not a word character (A word character is an alphanumeric character in the alnum class or an underscore `_`) -> **so this solution can lead to false positives if you allow underscores in your user names**.
- `|` means "or" and `$` means "end of string" so that `([[:>:]].*|$)` means "a word ending followed by any character any number of times OR end of the string"

You might need to adapt the regex following your needs, you have [some explanations here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-regular-expression-regexp.aspx/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just on right way with patterns search

```
  SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name LIKE '%w%';
```

But need to fetch rows like this to select more details

```
 <?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,email FROM people. 
WHERE id = '42'");
if (!$result) {
     echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // 42
echo $row[1]; // the email value
?>
```

Try this special pattern format in your query to avoid problems with withe space etc.

(?<=\s|^)@([\w@]+)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you saying the important part of this is the query? In that case, the query you provided is too specific; if I use `WHERE id='#'`, it doesn't include messages that simply mention that specific username. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: It seemsca special problem with username query in php. See additional informations above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312202/query-for-php-mysql-and-or-for-an-advanced-search